# Draw vertical line on horizontalBar at value 2.0

Tags: annotations, chart.js

I am trying to draw vertical line but Nothing is shown till now. Just Old horizontal bar graph is showing. I am using Chart.js annotation plugin and still nothing is appearing and there is no error shown in console. I am somehow following this [Jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mfjvfz0o/8/) but not exactly  this but If on this I can produce vertical line on point 2.0 ?

```
var ctxViolations = document.getElementById("myChartViolations");
var options = {
    scaleLabel: function(object) {
        return "      " + object.value;
    },
    responsive: true,
    pointDot: false
};

var myChartViolations = new Chart(ctxViolations, {
type: 'horizontalBar',

data: {
    labels: violations_labels,
    datasets: [{
            label: '# of Violations',
            showTooltip: true,
            data: violations_count_values,
            backgroundColor: '#ccccff',
            borderColor: '#000000',
            borderWidth: 0,
            fill: false
        },
        {
            type: 'line',
            label: 'Excessive Violations > 3',
            backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
            borderColor: '#ff0000',
            borderWidth: 0,
            pointStyle: 'line',
            data: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
        }
    ]
},
options: {
    responsive: true,

    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                // labelString: 'Violation Type'
            },
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                fixedStepSize: 1
            }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            display: true,
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Violation Count'
            },
            ticks: {
                autoSkip: false,
            },
            position: 'bottom'
        }]
    },
    hover: {
        mode: 'dataset'
    },
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: $scope.EstablishmentName.substring(0, 25) + ' Violations'
    },
    annotation: {
        annotations: [{
            type: 'line',
            mode: 'vertical',
            scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
            value: 2,
            borderColor: 'green',
            borderWidth: 3
        }]
    },

    tooltips: {
        mode: 'label'
    }
}
});

});

}
```

want to add line on 3.0

[image]

Comment: @ℊααnd I shared a image. I want a vertical line at just point 2.0.  (in short at the end of blue bar but bar will increase dynamically I want a fixed line at 2.0 ).

Comment: Can you provide values for `violations_count_values` and `violations_labels` ? I attempted to reproduce the error but the line is there (https://jsfiddle.net/g0v2wap5/). Only change to the code you posted was random data on those 2 variables and changing the `value` attribute on `annotations` to 3.

Comment: @RaquelGuimarães can You post this as answer ? :)

Comment: Sure thing @ephemeral :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g0v2wap5). Only change to the code you posted was random data on those 2 variables and changing the value attribute on annotations to 3

```
annotations: [{
            type: 'line',
            mode: 'vertical',
            scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
            value: 3, // <---
            borderColor: 'green',
            borderWidth: 3
        }]
```